# COBOL - Calling the Windows API Getsysteminfo()

Tags: windows, cobol

I am calling the windows API `Getsysteminfo()` to get the system information.
However, `SYSTEM_INFO` structure does not populate with the correct information.
The main suspect I think is the member dwActiveProcessorMask due to the fact it
can compile for a 32-bit or a 64-bit platform. I defined it as a 32-bit signed
integer. Below are the `COBOL` code:

```
identification division.
program-id. TEST.

Environment Division.
CONFIGURATION SECTION.

special-names.
     call-convention 74 is WinAPI.

working-storage section.
    01 DWORD           pic 9(9) comp-5 value 0 typedef.
    01 WORD            pic 9(5) comp-5 value 0 typedef.
    01 LPVOID          POINTER typedef.
    01 DWORD-PTR       POINTER typedef.

    01 SYSTEM-INFO.
       05  dwOemId                       DWORD.
       05  wProcessorArchitecture        WORD.
       05  wReserved                     WORD.
       05  dwPageSize                    DWORD.
       05  lpMinimumApplicationAddress   LPVOID.
       05  lpMaximumApplicationAddress   LPVOID.
       05  dwActiveProcessorMask         DWORD-PTR.
       05  dwNumberOfProcessors          DWORD.
       05  dwProcessorType               DWORD.
       05  dwAllocationGranularity       DWORD.
       05  wProcessorLevel               WORD.
       05  wProcessorRevision            WORD.

linkage section.
    01 LS-DWORD-PTR     DWORD.


procedure division WinApi.
100-MAIN SECTION 1.

         call winapi "GetSystemInfo" using
              by reference System-Info
         end-call

         set address of ls-dword-ptr to dwActiveProcessorMask
```

Thanks for your help...

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724381(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Using Windows 7 32-bit, Net Express COBOL compiler...

Comment: you should probably include the code. I can see a scrambled working storage section, but that doesn't really show me what you are doing.

Comment: edit the question and add that information. Also use the code-block markup. It's impossible to read as is. I would edit it myself, but there is a pending edit in the queue

Comment: Why don't you use `POINTER` for the pointer? Also `SYNCHRONIZED` may be used, too.

Comment: I used a pointer for the variable dword-ptr, no difference. I used the SYNC clause with the level 01 system-info sync. no difference. I used manual padding of four-bytes to align the structure manually: 05 filler pic x(4) to align the dword-ptr variable, no difference...

Comment: I already defined the DWORD-PTR as a pointer, makes no difference. The dword-ptr is a double word sized alias for _int3264 that must be resolved to either a 32-bit signed integer or a 64-bit signed integer....

Comment: There were three steps given. What did you get with all three done? `DWORD_PTR` is a pointer to `unsigned long` and `DWORD` is `unsigned long`. Recheck your reference.

Comment: 1). DWORD-PTR declared as a Pointer,  usage is pointer typedef. In the Linkage Section, 2). DWORD-PTR is defined as a variable sized Dword.    In the procedure division, 3). the address of the member dwActiiveprocessorMask was set into the variable LS-DWORD. When these three steps are implemented, they do NOT solve the problem. The function call does not populate the system-info structure with the correct information. The structure gets filled with large numbers that looks like random memory garbage...

Comment: See the additional suggestions in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

It has been about 20 years since I did such things; but I do recall there is no direct way to 'de-reference' a `C pointer` in `COBOL`. It must be done indirectly.

Change:

```
01 DWORD-PTR    pic s9(9) comp-5 value 0 typedef.
```

to

```
01 DWORD-PTR    POINTER typedef.
```

Add:

```
linkage section.
01 ls-dword DWORD.
```

After the `call` add:

```
set address of ls-dword to dwActiveProcessorMask
```

After the `set` statement, the content of `ls-dword` will be same as the content of `dwActiveProcessorMask`.

(In the 2002 standard, the `BASED` clause was added to handle these situations.)

---

This is the first part of `SYSTEM_INFO`.

```
typedef struct _SYSTEM_INFO {
  union {
    DWORD  dwOemId;
    struct {
      WORD wProcessorArchitecture;
      WORD wReserved;
    };
  };
  DWORD     dwPageSize;
```

which you defined as:

```
   05  dwOemId                       DWORD.
   05  wProcessorArchitecture        WORD.
   05  wReserved                     WORD.
   05  dwPageSize                    DWORD.
```

In COBOL, the `C` `union` becomes a `REDEFINES`, that is `wProcessorArchitecture` and `wReserved` occupy the same space as `dwOemId`. Since `dwOemId` is obsolete it should be deleted. In effect `SYSTEM-INFO` is 4-bytes longer than it should be.

Comment: Hi Rick, Thanks for your helpful pointers. When I removed dwOemId from system-info, ALL the members of the table were populated with Zeros only.  I even tried manual padding at different positions to align and SYNC all variables: 05 filler   pic x(4)....

Comment: @KellieFitton - You might try adding an `ON EXCEPTION` phrase to the `call` statement, to see if the call fails. Don't use `sync` or `filler`. Looking at the 'local variables' while 'debugging' in Visual Studio using `C++` 32-bit, shows that all variables are either two or four bytes. No other alignment is required in `COBOL`.